# DPDK cannot find -lnuma

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, dpdk

While compiling the dpdk 17.04 version, i'm getting following error at the end.

```
== Build drivers/event/skeleton
== Build drivers/event/sw
== Build drivers/event/octeontx
== Build app
== Build app/test-pmd
  LD testpmd
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lnuma
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
/home/root1/dpdk/dpdk-stable-17.08.1/mk/rte.app.mk:280: recipe for target 'testpmd' failed
make[5]: *** [testpmd] Error 1
/home/root1/dpdk/dpdk-stable-17.08.1/mk/rte.subdir.mk:63: recipe for target 'test-pmd' failed
make[4]: *** [test-pmd] Error 2
/home/root1/dpdk/dpdk-stable-17.08.1/mk/rte.sdkbuild.mk:76: recipe for target 'app' failed
make[3]: *** [app] Error 2
/home/root1/dpdk/dpdk-stable-17.08.1/mk/rte.sdkroot.mk:128: recipe for target 'all' failed
make[2]: *** [all] Error 2
/home/root1/dpdk/dpdk-stable-17.08.1/mk/rte.sdkinstall.mk:85: recipe for target 'pre_install' failed
make[1]: *** [pre_install] Error 2
/home/root1/dpdk/dpdk-stable-17.08.1/mk/rte.sdkroot.mk:107: recipe for target 'install' failed
make: *** [install] Error 2
```

Please suggest the solution.

Comment: What have you tried to achieve your wanted results? What has your research concerning your problem shown? Can you provide code of your tries? [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How much research effort is expected](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) might be helpful to improve your question.

Answer (score 1):

DPDK requires `libnuma-devel` as described in System Requirements:

http://dpdk.org/doc/guides/linux_gsg/sys_reqs.html

Answer (score 0):

Libnuma packages are optional build dependency. You can disable the same by editing the RTE_TARGET config file. So you can either install libnuma-dev package or disable on target. Please do the need ful